# iPhone app freezes on presentViewController with SLComposerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, social-framework

I am implementing sharing with Facebook and Twitter - On the simulator both of these work, but on my iPhone 4S running iOS6 the Facebook button freezes the app.  The code is the same as it is for the Twitter and functions the same (it hits `presentViewController`, then the app just stops responding).

The code is as follows:

```
SLComposeViewController *mulitpartPost = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        // Set the text of the tweet
        [mulitpartPost setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I've had a change in weight of "]];

        // Add the image to the tweet
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"fbProgPicShare"])
            [mulitpartPost addImage:[_imgCurrent image]];

        mulitpartPost.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult res){
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        };
        // Display the tweet sheet to the user
        [self presentViewController:mulitpartPost animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`isAvailableForServiceType` also returns `YES` if I put that into the code - so I cannot think of why this would freeze when the Twitter button works on the phone.  Both Twitter and FB accounts are setup.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Strange Fix**

It seems to work consistantly now that I do

```
// Display the tweet sheet to the user
if(!(multipartPost == nil))
        [self presentViewController:mulitpartPost animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Otherwise it still freezes.

Comment: Is `multipartPost == nil`?  Sometimes `composeViewControllerForServiceType` will return `nil` even if `isAvailableForServiceType` returns `YES`.

Comment: (On your device, not on the simulator.)

Comment: Permanent or temporary freeze?

Comment: Thank you for the replies,

I added your check for nil and suddenly it works every time.  I swear Obj-C does crazy things sometimes, I have no clue what the difference is.

Comment: I have the same issue, what is goning on?